# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'anwsers')

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why I can't iterate the array objects state in React.

How i iterate:

```
{all.map(item =>
   <div>
    {item.anwsers.map(item_2 => <h3>{item_2.isCorrect && item_2.anwser}</h3>)}
       <p>{item.question}</p>
   </div>
)}
```

How i fill it?

```
useEffect(() => {
        var seperate = questions[currentQuestion -1];
        setAll([...all, seperate])
    }, [currentQuestion])
```

Here is the array all:

[image: console.log]

The error message I'm getting:
[image: error In react]

Comment: Please show your `all` array. Could it be the typo `anwsers` instead of `answers`?

Comment: Your `all` array first item is `undefined`

Comment: yes, thats is the problem but I wonder how is the way around to this, because I want to keep null the first value, the second should be 0

Answer (score 1):

add `?` before the item to wait the useEffect. Example: `item?.anwsers.map...`

Comment: didn't worked, also can you explain the ? what it has to do with effect?

Comment: useEffect procs after mounting and updating the first time and then after an item in the list  gets updated. So the state might not be ready before the first useEffect which might result in an empty array (because if it was null, `all` will return an error). So we say if its undefined, just skip it for now, and when the next re-render happens, it will mount the answers. If it didnt work, check the spelling of answers. @hegibo2346

Comment: I see thanks, but this is not the problem, thought I learned something

Comment: you are welcome. It solves the problem of the first item being undefined as well, so you might want what else is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it with a if, so if its undefined to skip then show the questions, and this is what I exactly wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **filter()** method for removing **undefined** elements

```
{all.filter(a => a !== undefined).map(item =>
  <div>
    {item.anwsers.map(item_2 => item_2.isCorrect && <h3>{ item_2.anwser}</h3>)}
    <p>{item.question}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I did something similar with if, but this is a better way of doing it maybe, but I didn't tried

Comment: I think `filter` will make it slower as it needs to iterate first filtering the array and then do the second iterate mapping the array compared to put `if` inside `map`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to remove all falsy element values in your array:

```
{all.filter(Boolean).map(item =>
   <div>
    {item.anwsers.map(item_2 => <h3>{item_2.isCorrect && item_2.anwser}</h3>)}
       <p>{item.question}</p>
   </div>
)}
```

This way will removes all these values:

1. empty string
2. false
3. 0
4. null
5. undefined

Note: Use this solution if your Array's elements are just array, object or none-falsy values.